# Output Values from Regression Line inside Matplotlib window

Tags: python, matplotlib, textbox, regression

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([6, 15, 24, 33, 41, 52, 59, 66, 73, 81])
y = np.array([5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50])

coef = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
poly1d_fn = np.poly1d(coef)  # to create a linear function with coefficients

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', x, poly1d_fn(x), '-b')
plt.errorbar(x, poly1d_fn(x), yerr=poly1d_fn(x) - y, fmt='.k')
plt.show()
```

I have a working code which produces based upon my input a graph with error bars and the regression line. That's all fine. Now what I wanted to do is add a text box below and once a user inputs a number, e.g. 12 it outputs the according value (re regression line).

```
left, bottom, width, height = 0.15, 0.02, 0.7, 0.10

plt.subplots_adjust(left=left, bottom=0.25) # Make space for the slider


input_field = plt.axes([left, bottom, width, height])
box = TextBox(input_field, 'value')
```

I tried it with this approach. Though being unsuccessful: I can't get it to take a value and output it on the GUI interface matplotlib provides. The field would need to be checked for every input. Matplotlib offers `on_text_change(self, func)`or `on_submit(self, func)`, so that might be working - but how to output?
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple `Text` artist to display the result. But being fancy, I would also display lines on the graph showing the input and output values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([6, 15, 24, 33, 41, 52, 59, 66, 73, 81])
y = np.array([5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50])

coef = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
poly1d_fn = np.poly1d(coef)  # to create a linear function with coefficients


def submit(val):
    try:
        x = float(val)
        y = poly1d_fn(x)
        ax.annotate('', xy=(x,0), xycoords=('data','axes fraction'),
                        xytext=(x,y), textcoords='data',
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-', ls='--'))
        ax.annotate(f'{x:.2f}', xy=(x,0), xycoords=('data','axes fraction'))
        ax.annotate('', xy=(0,y), xycoords=('axes fraction','data'),
                        xytext=(x,y), textcoords='data',
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-', ls='--'))
        ax.annotate(f'{y:.2f}', xy=(0,y), xycoords=('axes fraction','data'))
        output_box.set_text(f'Result = {y:.2f}')
        plt.draw()
    except ValueError:
        pass

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro', x, poly1d_fn(x), '-b')
ax.errorbar(x, poly1d_fn(x), yerr=poly1d_fn(x) - y, fmt='.k')

left, bottom, width, height, pad = 0.15, 0.02, 0.3, 0.10, 0.1
fig.subplots_adjust(left=left, bottom=0.25) # Make space for the slider
input_field = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])
text_box = matplotlib.widgets.TextBox(input_field, 'value')
text_box.on_submit(submit)
output_box = fig.text(left+width+pad, bottom+height/2, s='Result = ', va='center')
```

[image]

Comment: Hey apparently you can only enter a value once - changes aren't recognized. Moreover, (if it's possible to re-enter the value field) will the square in the graph remain or may it be deleted? Adding to this, it is possible to enter a y-value and get the according x-value?

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: cannot reproduce. I can enter multiple values with the code above

Comment: And what about changing it to entering the y-values to get x-value output?

Comment: any idea on how to approach this

Comment: Just create a new TextBox with a different callback and calculate the x value from the y value using the inverse function. Why don't you try it and ask another question if you encounter a specific probem